# В чем разница вызовов(обьявлений) этих обьектов?

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер, начал изучать js около месяц назад, начал с видеокурсов Специалист. В общем там обьекты обьявлялись и вызывались такими вот способами:

1)

```
var iamobj=new Object;  
  iamobj.name="giggity";  
  iamobj.show=function(){  
  alert(this.name);  
}

iamobj.show();
```

ну здесь понятно, обьявили обьект, обьявили свойство и метод, затем вызвали метод

2)

```
function Test(name){  
    this.name=name;  
    this.show=function(){  
        alert(this.name)  
    }  
}

var iamobj=new Test("giggity");  
iamobj.show();
```

что имеем здесь: снизу обьявили обьект и сразу-же присвоили ему функцию, куда передали значение, затем вызвали метод

Здесь вроде бы как все понятно, не ясно только какой метод когда лучше использовать.. но затем начал вчитываться в статью про свойства и методы обьектов на javascript.ru и вообще запутался
синтаксис совершенно другой.. сейчас покажу

3)

```
var iamobj={  
    read:function(){  
        this.name=prompt("имя?")  
    },   
    show:function(){  
        return this.name  
    }  
}

iamobj.read();  
alert(iamobj.show())
```

собственно.. вопрос.. что это вообще такое и зачем? 
внизу сразу вызывается метод у обьекта iamobj, потом поднимаемся вверх и только тут обьявляем обьект (var), считываем значения имени в методе.. и снизу вызываем еще один метод чтобы показать. между методами в обьекте обьязана стоять запятая.. зачем столько вариатов обьявлений? у каждого из них есть какое-то преимущество в определенном условии?

4)

```
function show(){  
    this.name=name;  
    alert(this.name);  
}

var iamobj=new show("giggity")
```

снизу обьявили обьект, тут же вызвали ф-цию и передали в нее значение, та берет значение, присваивает и выводит.. легкий способ, но опять же, синтаксис другой

5)

```
function iamobj(){  
    this.show=function(){  
        var a=prompt("name?")  
        alert(a);  
    }  
}

new iamobj().show();
```

опять же новый синтаксис, внизу обьявляем обьект и тут же пишем какой метод в нем хотим вызвать, обьект являетсо функцией(?), внутри которого каждое свойство = метод (так чтоли? зачем?)

в общем, обьясните кто-то пожалуйста зачем столько вариантов разных есть и в чем преимущество каждого? хотя бы приблизительно, ато я что-то вообще уже теряюсь

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Столько возможностей объявления для нашего с вами удобства, правда что касается примера инициализации объекта с помощью ключевого слова new - это нечто иное, если быть точным то это одна из возможных реализаций ООП, раз уже задел этот вопрос - немного о концепции.

Любая функция может вызываться при помощи оператора new, функция, далее конструктор, которая вызывается при помощи оператора new получает на вход переменную `this` которая является еще не созданным объектом (который она, собственно и вернет), в контексте ООП - экземпляром "класса". Не смотря на похожий синтаксис - ООП в javascript устроено не так как везде, если быть более точным - построено на прототипировании.

Теперь непосредственно о прототипах - у любой функции есть прототип (если быть точным у любого объекта, но в нашем случае речь не об этом), прототип это объект к которому имеют доступ все экземпляры конструктора("класса") ( сам по себе он всего-лишь JavaScript объект ), в котором целесообразно хранить общие методы или свойства для всех экземпляров конструктора("класса"). Что же касается специфических свойств и методов - их необходимо (читай по хорошему) инициализировать в конструкторе. Важно добавить - prototype это 1 единственный объект, независимо от количества экземпляров, соответственно, если, например, писать так:

```
var User = function( username ) {
    this.__username = username;
    this.getUsername = function(){
      return this.__username; 
    }
    this.setUsername = function( username ){
       this.__username = username;
    }
}

var user1 = new User('Vasya');
var user2 = new User('Petya');
```

В этом случае - методы getUsername и setUsername делают одну и ту-же работу, но, что касаемо памяти - это разные функции, в этом можно легко убедиться:

```
alert( user1.getUsername === user2.getUsername ) // false
alert( user1.setUsername === user2.setUsername ) // false
```

Соответственно с точки зрения памяти и вообще здравого смысла - этот подход не лучшее решение. Но теперь о том как все это нужно делать в javascript'e, перепишем пример

```
var User = function( username ) {
    this.__username = username;
}
User.prototype = {
    getUsername : function(){
      return this.__username; 
    },
    setUsername : function( username ){
       this.__username = username;
    }
}

var user1 = new User('Vasya');
var user2 = new User('Petya');

alert( user1.getUsername === user2.getUsername ); // true
alert( user1.setUsername === user2.setUsername ); // true
```

Как мы видим - использовав прототип мы добились того что наши методы `getUsername` и `setUsername` не плодятся для каждого вызова конструктора, а инициализируются единожды, что уже совсем другое дело с точки зрения памяти и здравого смысла.

Ну а что касаемо разницы между записями вида

```
var obj;

obj = {};
obj.somePropName = someValue;
// ........

obj = {
   somePropName : someValue,
   // ........
};

obj = new Object();
obj.somePropName = someValue;
// ........
```

Отличия нет, по крайней мере с точки зрения производительности. Есть разница только с точки зрения работы геттеров и сеттеров в контексте глобального конструктора Object, но я не думаю что вам это принципиально.

По поводу последнего примера, на самом деле, грубо, происходит следующее:

```
function iamobj(){  
    this.show=function(){  
        var a = prompt("name?")  
        alert(a);  
    }  
}

// new iamobj().show();
var obj = new iamobj();
obj.show();
```

Точно так-же мы могли бы поступить, например, с DOM элементом:

```
 document.getElementById("someElementId").onclick = function(){
     /* observer code here... */
 }
```

С точки зрения целесообразности - применимо только в том случае, если объект не будет использоваться далее, и даже не смотря на это Крокфорд (и я за компанию), все-же, советуют заранее объявлять переменные перед тем как с ними работать.

Если вам нужен статический метод, то просто используйте объект без вызова функции в контексте конструктора с помощью new (что-то типа `iamobj.show = function(){/*...*/}`, `iamobj.show()`).

Вообще надо понимать что и для чего используется, если отбросить `new` и все из него выплывающее - объект это всего-лишь хэш, то что в объекте могут храниться функции - особенность языка, то что функции хэша имеют доступ в теле функции к хэшу через перменную `this` - так-же особенности языка, благодаря им можно городить пространства имен и легко и без напряга писать singleton'ы (и многое другое), но, как-бы там не было - в своем элементарном проявлении это всего-лишь ассоциативный массив.

Надеюсь этой информации достаточно, пожалуй прекращаю т.к. и так ответ "немного" растянулся.

Comment: Хотел добавить - Крокфорд рекомендует использовать фигурные скобки, вместо `new Object()`

Comment: Ничего себе, уверен такой ответ поможет еще многим людям...

Спасибо :)

Comment: На здоровье =)

Answer (score 2):

Разница по большому счету только в том что объявляется "класс" или "объект".
Из класса можно получить несколько объектов, объект сам по себе, второй такой же надо будет создавать copy-paste.
Объект создается в 1 и 3, в остальных случаях объявляется класс, потом создается объект. 
Объект Function в иерархии типов наследован от Object. В дополнение к методам Object есть свои методы... ну и функцию можно вызвать :)
Как писать в собственных скриптах по большому счету все равно, нагляднее будет единым стилем без увеличения числа сущностей без необходимости...